# How to download , add NCurses to Code::Blocks 16.01 IDE for Windows 10

Tags: c, windows-10, codeblocks, ncurses

I cannot find `NCurses` for my **Code::Blocks** 16.01 IDE for Windows 10.
I found [this](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) , but did not know how to use it even I tried to link it in the linker setting in **Code::Blocks**. Also I don't know if it's suitable for Windows or it's specifically for Linux.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with MinGW ? (Code Blocks is an IDE not a compiler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ncurses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is a text-based graphics library for C that is
supported on unix-like OSes, not on Windows. So you can use
it if you're writing C on a unix-like OS (such as Linux). Your choice of IDE doesn't matter.

On Windows, you could use it under a unix-like environment such as [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)
or [MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/), but you would hardly want to
go to that length *merely* for the sake of writing `ncurses` programs.

There is a very similar library, [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/)
that is supported on Windows, and also a [Project Pluto fork of PDCurses](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm)
The first of those provides a [binary distibution](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/),
but it dates from 2008. In both cases, there are links to GitHub repositories hosting
the latest source code, from which you may build the library yourself, following the instructions you will find in the project's `README.md` file.